# Correct use of logical operator in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following `If` block that runs upon pressing a command button on a form object. This should simply check to see if any of the four mentioned text boxes are empty and if so, display a message box then exit that procedure so that the user can correct the fields and continue.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.ToString()) || 
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtID.ToString()) ||
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSalary.ToString()) ||
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtERR.ToString()))
 {
  MessageBox.Show("One or more text fields are empty or hold invalid data, please correct this to continue","Data Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  return;
 }
```

I've left all the text fields blank, and even tried putting white space characters in but the conditional code isn't being executed. As the code isn't executing I'm assuming there is something wrong with my if statement, perhaps I'm not using the 'or' operator `||` correctly? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your variables actually point to null or empty variables? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: The logical operator seems OK to me. Check your text field values.

Comment: you are missing on .Text Property For Eg:  txtName.Text

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm evaluating the textbox objects directly, should I be passing the value to a string variable and comparing that instead?

Comment: Depending on what object / control you are dealing with, you should have a property to get it's value. You have to compare the value. Try putting a breakpoint right before your condition and check the value of txtName.ToString(). It won't be empty.

Comment: `txtName.ToString()` does not represent the text inside the `TextBox`'s field. (Look at what it returns.) You need `txtName.Text`

Comment: Look @Magnus's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are checking textboxes you need to get the text from the textbox.

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) || ...
```

As a little bonus you could also write it like this:

```
if(new [] {txtName, txtID, txtSalary, txtERR}
  .Any(tb => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text)))
{
   MessageBox.Show("One or more text fields are empty or hold invalid data, please correct this to continue","Data Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Oh how embarassing! I'm trying to learn C# coming from VBA - quite a big jump. This was the first response so as soon as it will allow me I'll accept as the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That bonus is going to save me so much time as I've got a few other forms to create in this project. Glad I asked now, thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Text` property of `TextBox`. `ToString` method returns  string "System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase". This string is obviously never empty or null.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) || 
 string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtID.Text) ||
 string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSalary.Text) ||
 string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtERR.Text)) 
 {
  MessageBox.Show("One or more text fields are empty or hold invalid data, please correct this to continue","Data Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  return;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If txtName, txtID etc. name of controls then you need to refer to .Text property. Try something like snippet below:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) || 
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtID.Text) ||
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSalary.Text) ||
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtERR.Text))
 {
  MessageBox.Show("One or more text fields are empty or hold invalid data, please correct this to continue","Data Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  return;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox.ToString()` will return the type of the `TextBox` - thus this will never be `NullOrWhiteSpace`. What you want is to check the contents of the `Text` property like so:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text || 
 string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtID.Text) ||
 string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSalary.Text) ||
 string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtERR.Text))
 {
      MessageBox.Show("One or more text fields are empty or hold invalid data, please correct this to continue","Data Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
      return;
 }
```

Comment: Aah, okay this makes more sense thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use **IsNullOrWhiteSpace** for that kind of test, instead i prefer to use **IsNullOrEmpty**

try this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)||...)
{...
```

or maybe txtName is returning the TEXT object...try this then

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text.toString())||...)
{...
```

Comment: I believe this wouldn't capture the user just entering a space, for example, into a field though.